# bootstrapping Nash-Sutcliffe Efficieny in R

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I'm trying to bootstrap the statistic, Nash-Sutcliffe Efficiency (NSE), in R. It's used to evaluate the performance of hydrologic model simulation data against observed data.  A function within the package 'hydroGOF' exists to calculate the statistic (NSE()). The definition of the statistic is as follows:

> Description
>
> Nash-Sutcliffe efficiency between sim and obs, with treatment of missing values.
>
> Usage
>
> *NSE(sim, obs, ...)*

I can successfully bootstrap the correlation coefficient using this code (The object 'Run' is a two-column data frame (observed runoff and simulated runoff):

```
mycorRun <- function(Run, i) cor(Run[i,])[1,2]
bootcorRun <- boot(Run, mycorRun,R=10000)
```

However, when I try to imitate this with the NSE function I get the following error:

`library(hydroGOF)`

`observed.runoff <- c(0.3, 0.5, 1.1, 0.6, 0.1)
simulated.runoff <- c(0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.4, 0.3)
runoff <- data.frame(observed.runoff, simulated.runoff)`

`myNSERun <- function(runoff, i) NSE(runoff[i,])[1,2]`

`bootNSERun <- boot(runoff, myNSERun, R=10000)`

**Error in as.matrix(obs) : argument "obs" is missing, with no default**

Any thoughts on how to write the statistic function? I've tried creating my own function with x & y variables instead of observed & simulated, but it gives me the same error.

Comment: So you have chosen not to post the code that generates the error? Why would you do such a thing?

Comment: Thanks @BondedDust. I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

Remove [1,2] in your code --> NSE(runoff[i,]). However, I am not sure if it is a wise choice to bootstrap the NSE as it there is temporal correlation in the time series and ordinary bootstrapping usually depends on iid variables.